# How to detect if the point is at a closing delimiter?

Tags: regular-expressions

How to detect if the point is at a closing delimiter?

For example:

- in Elisp: `)`
- in LaTeX: `}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This simple code:

```cl
(looking-at "\\s)")
```

Comment: [Reference - Syntax Class Table](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html)

Comment: Thanks this works well. When the cursor is at `]` in `(global-set-key [f7] 'some-command)`, `(looking-at "\\s)")` returns nil. Is there an explanation for this? I suspect that here `]` is not a closing delimiter, but I am not sure.

Comment: It returns `t` for me with `emacs -Q`. Check your config.

Answer (score 4):

In a [syntax table](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSyntaxTable), closing delimiters are denoted by `)`.  You can check the syntax of the character at point with the following predicate function, which will return true if the character is a closing delimiter:

```el
(defun close-delimiter-p ()
  "Is character at point a closing delimiter according to the
syntax table?"
  (eq ?\) (char-syntax (char-after))))
```

Comment: Thanks this works well. When the cursor is at `]` in `(global-set-key [f7] 'some-command)`, `close-delimiter-p` returns nil. Is there an explanation for this? I suspect that here `]` is not a closing delimiter, but I am not sure.